# Java Mono or Flux needed as response for "when" mock with webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am writing some contract tests and I am trying to mock my controller in order to test the wanted method. My method should only return status code 200, so not an object, and I do not know how to write this with Mono or Flux and I get an error because of that.

I tried something like this, but it does not work:

```
Mono<Integer> response = Mono.just(Response.SC_OK);
when(orchestration.paymentReceived(purchase)).thenReturn(response);
```

How should I write my "when" part in order to verify it returns status code 200?

Comment: You need to write a test with WebTestClient.bindToController. This way you will be sure what status is retuned after method call. Pure JUnit tests do not cover this. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/pdf/testing-webtestclient.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to check response status code you will need to write a more complicated test, using WebTestClient. Like so:

```
Service service = Mockito.mock(Service.class);
WebTestClient client = WebTestClient.bindToController(new TestController(service)).build();
```

Now you are able to test:

- serialization to JSON or other types
- content type
- response code
- path to your method
- invoked method (POST,GET,DELETE, etc)

Unit tests do not cover above topics.

```
// init mocks
when(service.getPersons(anyInt())).thenReturn(Mono.just(person));    

// execute rest resource
client.get() // invoked method
  .uri("/persons/1") // requested path
  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .exchange()
  .expectStatus().isOk() // response code
  .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .expectBody()
  .jsonPath("$.firstName").isEqualTo(person.getFirstName())
  .jsonPath("$.lastName").isEqualTo(person.getLastName())
  

// verify you have called your expected methods
verify(service).getPerson(1);
```

You can find more examples [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/pdf/testing-webtestclient.pdf). Above test is also does not require Spring context, can work with mock services.